# Search for a counterexample for a Pell’s equation conjecture

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let the constant $d$ in Pell’s equation $x^2-dy^2=1$ be a prime such that $d=n(n+1)(n+2)+1$.
Now compare the - lowest - solution for $d$ and $d-1$. My conjecture is that the solution for $d$ is much higher than for $d-1$, i.e. for $n(n+1)(n+2 )$. This came up in my attempts to understand the special case of $d=61$ being $3\times 4 \times 5+1$ with its high solution.

Someone told me that in some cases the reverse would be true, but he didn’t offer an example. He did however make some calculations showing that my statement is true for $d < 1 500 000$. While this is a large number it still corresponds to a relatively modest number of cases, only 38 (up to $n=115$).

Comment: What exactly is the question in this? Also, I've converted this to LaTeX quickly; please do try to use it in future!

Comment: The question is:is there an n so that the lowest solution for d=n(n+1)(n+2) is higher than the lowest solution for the prime number d+1.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting conjecture! If my calculation is correct, it goes unchallenged for quite some time before failing at $d=34965457$ (corresponding to $n=326$). The smallest $x$ for $(d-1)$ is

```
25095664791553218669437437017106409143490137922195
56605243569408784102967806403079182710704502809602
76272541590853007432744322926326067853070023625443
07998378733697133994169449962329077423177517193117
73182806455
```

while the smallest one for $d$ is "just"

```
27069794535634534410598514149614146407632935632204
746423979023754891934010659911327241899199134849
```

The conjecture also seems to fail for $d=45118012441$ ($n=3559$) and $d=63760295881$ ($n=3994$) and I believe these are the only counter-example for $n\leq 5000$ (which produce $829$ cases of prime $d$).

Comment: Thank you very much,it was very interesting.